# How can I install After Effects CC 2020 in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: wine, playonlinux, 20.10, winetricks, crossover

I changed my Operating system from windows to Ubuntu 20.10
I want to know how to install After Effects CC 2020 in Ubuntu with wine or playonlinux or some other

Comment: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-install-and-use-wine-run-windows-applications-linux/ https://itsfoss.com/use-windows-applications-linux/ Both of these tutorials will help. These are not specifically related to installing After Effects, but will work after you know the basics with these articles Also, check if your app works with WINE on [WineHQ's Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org)